# Parallel transport and Gaussian curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

In do Carmo's book, we are told that the angle between any unit vector $w_0$ and the vector $w$ resulting from its parallel transport around a closed path on a surface, back to the location of $w_0$ is

$ \displaystyle
\Delta \phi = \int K d\sigma
$

where $K$ is the Gaussian curvature on the surface and the integral is taken over the portion of the surface enclosed by the closed path.

Now, let's say we have  a unit sphere $S^2$ with a unit vector $w_0$ sitting on the equator, and we parallel transport it around the equator.  Since $K=1$, we should get $\Delta \phi = 2 \pi$.

However, what if $w_0=\hat{z}$?  I try and try to see it otherwise, but it seems to me that the parallel transport of $\hat{z}$ around the equator must be simply $\hat{z}$ and therefore $\Delta \phi$ must be zero, not $2 \pi$.

Someone please tell me where I am going wrong!  This seems like it should be completely straightforward!

Comment: It will point the same way if it has turned by $2\pi$.

Comment: @Knaus  Yes.  But I can't see how it turns at all during transport.

Comment: Well, how would you see it turning? You can only compare what you started with, with what you ended up with. And then $\Delta\phi=2\pi=0$, so the turning is maybe not so clear. 
To see the turning, try rather going only half-way around the equator, and then going straight over the north pole. You have enclosed now only one forth of the unit sphere. Can you visualise that $\Delta\phi =\pi$ is correct?

Comment: @Knaus  OK.  Yes.  I see that.  But back to the equator, I can't see anywhere that the vector rotates.  Where, for instance, would it become $-\hat{z}$?

Comment: There is no canonical way to compare tangentvectors at different points. That's an important lesson. If you insist, we can however define one, at least for the equator: Let's identify the tangentspaces at points on the equator with the tangentspace at the north pole, by parallel transport along the (unique) shortest path to the north pole. (This does not extend to all of $S^2$ of course, since uniqueness fail at the south pole.) Then you get $-\hat z$ when you're half way around the equator. Can you see the vector at the north pole spinning as you traverse the equator?

Comment: @Knaus  OK.  Yes. I see.  Thanks for this conversation.  It reassures me that I think I know what is going on.  However, then, it seems that we can use the integral of $K$ to determine what $\Delta \phi$ will be under parallel transport.  But given the ambiguity between $\phi=0,2\pi,4\pi$ etc, we can't use $\Delta \phi$ to determine the $K$ integral unambiguously.  This seems "unsatisfying" somehow.  :-)

Comment: You might want to check pp. 79-83 of my differential geometry text, linked in my profile. There are several issues. As Knaus points out, holonomy (the angle $\Delta \phi$ is really only defined mod $2\pi$). But there's also an issue of how you visualize the turning relative to a given frame.

Comment: @TedShifrin  Thanks!  Downloaded it.  Will take a look!

Comment: Hello! Where in Do Carmo's book did you see this result? Also, does a similar result hold in any dimension (a formula for the angle between the start and end vector of parallel transport along a closed curve)?